# How to upgrade pandas 2.0rc in VSCode

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

Trying to upgrade to pandas 2.0rc in VSCode using the jupyter notebook extension.

```
! python -m pip install --upgrade pip
! pip install --pre pandas==2.0.0rc0
import pandas as pd

pd.__version__
```

The result is:
After the installation stuff...

```
Successfully installed pandas-2.0.0rc0
```

So why does this still appear for the version?

```
'1.5.2'
```

Comment: In general, in the current Jupyter ecosystem, your command `! pip install --pre pandas==2.0.0rc0` should be `%pip install --pre pandas==2.0.0rc0` for a better experience in the long run. There was a magic command variation added a few years ago to make sure the steps occur in the environment the notebook kernel is using. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic `%pip install` command. The exclamation point alone doesn't necessarily insure it happens in the right environment.

Comment: A better way is to select the correct interpreter and install the package by command `pip install` in the terminal, so that you do not need to restart jupyter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy answer. Restart VSCode. And then it works.